# How to reindex "pg_amop_opc_strat_index" without access psql?

Tags: postgresql

This is the background... one of our server is crashed and I can't start the postgresql up. Then, I looked in the log and it said that it can't find "pg_clog/0044". I also noticed that the pg_clog folder was gone under the rdbms/data folder. So, I created the pg_clog folder and 256 byte blank file which named 0044 to fool it. The result was good which I can start the database up.
However, when I tried to log in to psql. There was FATAL error and stated that "pg_amop_opc_strat_index" contains unexpected zero page please "REINDEX" it.
So, I wonder that is it possible to REINDEX "pg_amop_opc_strat_index" without access the psql(Because I can't access it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ignore_system_indexes will probaly help you. Found in [the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-developer.html)
Once things appear to be working, I would advise you to backup the installaion, drop (or rename) the database, and recreate it from the backup.

Comment: Don't forget to dump and restore. There may be other hidden damage still lurking in there.